# Setting screen resolution for PHP cURL request

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, screen-scraping, resolution

I was wondering if it is possible to force a screen resolution (for example: 1920 x 1080) for the php curl request, as I need to scrape some sites for images, but they come at 300px width, whereas visiting the site through the browser @ 1920 x 1080 will provide 620px images. I cannot just replace the file names as the paths are different for different sizes.

Here's my very basic curl function:

```
private function curlPage($url)
{
    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        $retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
        curl_close($ch);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e;
    }
    return $retValue;
}
```

If this isn't possible through cURL, is there any other PHP libs that could do something like this? I know it is achievable through a headless browser like phantomJs, combined with casper or some other extension, but i would prefer to keep it PHP.

Comment: utterly impossible. curl has no screen, and HTTP itself doesn't care about screens. your browser gets different sizes because it can run javascript, which CAN access the browser's screen stats. you would have to slurp down whatever html/js the site uses, execute it, and then replicate whatever it does to determine screen sizes. e.g. set a cookie or whatever.   once that's done, THEN curl can fool the site in thinking it's a 1920x1080 screen.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, makes perfect sense. I will be scraping multiple sites so replicating dummy user activity to achieve the resolution is not really an option. I guess ill scrape everything but the images, and leave that for PhantomJs to handle separately.